# Combinations vs permutations with replacement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The formulas for combinations and permutations with replacement are, respectively:

$$
C = \binom{n + k - 1}{k} \\
P = n^k
$$

Where $n$ and $k$ correspond to the number of distinct objects we are to draw $k$ times from with replacement.

My question is I can't wrap my head around why $C * k! \neq P$.

$C$ is the number of ways we can draw $k$ (not necessarily) items from $n$ distinct items with replacement. Here, order does not matter. To account for order mattering, I multiply by $k!$. So why isn't $C * k! = P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are fewer orders if some of the elements match.  If you have the combination $1,1,2$ there are only $3$, not $3!=6$ orders for these elements.  You therefore cannot just multiply the number of combinations by $k!$ to get the number of permutations.

Comment: Ah yes. This is also precisely the reason why multiplying by $k!$ to combinations without replacement gets us the correct formula for permutations without replacement right? Because in the without replacement situation, you can't have matching elements.

Comment: That is correct.